# The system of equations $x^2 + y^2 - x - 2y = 0$ and $x + 2y = c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have

$(1.) \quad x^2 + y^2 - x - 2y = 0 \\
(2.) \quad x + 2y = c$

Solving for $y$ in $(2.)$ gives

$y = (c - x) / 2$

Is there a way to simplify equation $(1.)$?

Because at the end I arrive at

$c^2 - 2x - c = 0$

and can't proceed. Need to get typical form of square equation $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$.

The solution for $c$ is $0$ or $5$.

**EDIT 1:**

For what real values of the parameter do the common solutions of the following pairs of simultaneous equations became identical?

(g) $ \quad x^2 + y^2 - x - 2y = 0, \quad x + 2y = c$,  Ans. c = 0 or 5.

The process is to solve for $y$, then to substitute that into second equation.
From that we get A, B and C. Delta being $B^2 - 4AC$ we can get parameter.

So

$y = (c - x) / 2$

$x^2 + y^2 - x -2y = 0$

$x^2 + ((c-x)/2)^2 - x - 2 * ((c-x)/2) = 0$

and i got lost...

Comment: So you need to solve this system with respect to $x,y$ given a parameter $c$?

Comment: Yes, in a way. I'll add more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you substitute correctly, you will get the equation $5\,{x}^{2}-2\,c\,x+{c}^{2}-4\,c=0$.

If you solve this, you will get $x = \frac{1}{5}(c \pm 2\sqrt{c(5-c)})$. The other value is given by $y=\frac{1}{2}(c-x)$, but you don't need this to answer your question.

If the two sets of solutions have the same values, then we must have $c(5-c)=0$, hence $c=0$ or $c=5$.

**Addendum**: To get the above equation, replace $y$ in $x^2+y^2-x-2y=0$ by $y = \frac{1}{2}(c-x)$ (from the second equation). That is, the equation
\begin{eqnarray}
x^2+\frac{1}{4}(c-x)^2 -x -(c-x) &=& \frac{1}{4}(4x^2+(c-x)^2 -4c) \\
&=& \frac{1}{4}(5 x^2-2 c x +c^2-4c)
\end{eqnarray}
Then the solutions are (ignoring the $\frac{1}{4}$, of course):
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \frac{1}{10}\left(2c \pm \sqrt{4 c^2-20(c^2-4c)} \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{10}\left(2c \pm \sqrt{16 c(5-c)} \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{5}\left(c \pm 2\sqrt{ c(5-c)} \right) 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: That is correct but now what i need :) I'll add more details.

Comment: I have added more solution :-).

Comment: Half an hour has passed. It is past midnight here. I'll have to continue tomorrow. I am figuring out how you got that `x`. I completely forgot how to simplify square root. Otherwise i think this is it. Well, if it's not too much of a hassle, can you please explain how you got `x` or give some links?

Comment: There isn't much to simplify. Just be careful with your expansion. See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Ok that is it. You used quadratic equation formula with isolating x. Got it. Thank you for helping me about these mundane things :)

Comment: @MartinBerger: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You're intersecting a circle with the straight lines parallel to $x+2y=0$.

The circle can be written, by completing the squares, as
$$
x^2 -2\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{4} + y^2 - 2y + 1 = \frac{1}{4}+1
$$
or, writing the squares,
$$
\biggl(x-\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^2+(y-1)^2=\frac{5}{4}
$$
Thus the lines you're looking for must have distance $\sqrt{5}/2$ from the center $(1/2,1)$.

The formula for the distance of a point from a line gives then
$$
\frac{\left|\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot1-c\right|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
that becomes
$$
2\left|\frac{5}{2}-c\right|=5.
$$
This in turn gives the two equations
$$
5-2c=5,\qquad -5+2c=5
$$
that have solutions, respectively, $c=0$ and $c=5$.

You can also solve the system by substitution. From the second equation you get $x=c-2y$ and, substituting in the quadratic equation,
$$
(c-2y)^2+y^2-(c-2y)-2y=0
$$
Developing and simplifying, you get
$$
5y^2-4cy+c^2-c=0
$$
that has coincident roots when the discriminant is zero:
$$
(4c)^2-4\cdot 5(c^2-c)=0
$$
that becomes
$$
-4c^2+20c=0
$$
that is, $c^2-5c=0$. The solutions are $c=0$ and $c=5$.